# What kind of bird is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

[image]

Found in southwest Michigan.  It appears to have fallen from a nest.

Comment: It's clearly a heron of some kind. My money's on a juvenile Great Blue Heron, but I will need to double-check their juvenile plumage before I can be sure.

Comment: Please provide the approximate size of the bird. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The body shape does seem to indicate it's some kind of heron/egret (12 species, of which, have been previously found in Michigan [according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_birds_of_Michigan#Bitterns,_herons,_and_egrets)]).

The seemingly large size from your picture (please edit with actual or best approximation of size), the tufted feathers on the head, white face, and the start of a black line on the anterior edge of the eye all suggest that this could be a great blue heron.

Great blue herons are typically grey (not the dark almost black of your specimen), but I did find some photos with nestlings /fledglings with darker plumage, including below:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ardea_herodias_at_the_nest_11.jpg)</sup>